# jQuery - How to not execute a single line command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, switch-statement

I am relatively new in web development, so not sure I am explaining myself with the right terms, but have come to this little issue in a small project of mine:

I have a navigation menu with functionality (mainly style related) added through a switch. When browsing the mobile version of the site, the elements inside the menu change differently and as that I want that some of the commands listed on the switch case to not be executed. Here's a simplified example in the code I have:

```
//main (desktop) site functionality
$(".nav").click(function(event) {

    var what = event.target.className;

    switch (what){
        case "item 1":
            if ($(".text1").css("display") == "none"){
                $(".text1").css("display", "block");

                //this below is the line I don't want it to execute when on mobile
                $(".item5").css("margin-top","196px");
            } else {
                $("text1").css("display", "none");
                $(".item5").css("margin-top","0");
            }
            break;
    });

    //This is the function I use to know you are browsing on a mobile,
    //where the main change inside the CSS media query is not displaying the "scroller"
    function checkif(){
        if ($(".scroller").css("display") == "none" ){
        $(".item5").insertAfter($(".item12"));
        if($(".text1").css("display") == "block"){
            $(".item5").css("margin-top","0");
        }
    }
});
```

This is simplified, the changes within cases are more than just a margin, I change color, text, display of multiple elements. As that I don't want it to just not execute the switch, just to read the properties of the checkif() function and execute those instead of the ones in the switch when overlapping (as in the margin).
Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you are trying to do things with javascript that you should be doing in css and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Use a condition on the width of the window

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the key to your solution is to find whether the user is using a mobile device or not.

Let me suggest you another way to detect mobile device instead of your `checkif()` function.

```js
function isMobile(){
    // Get device user agent string
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;

    // Regular expression to sniff user agent
    var regexp = /mobi/i;

    // Test if the regexp exists in the user agent string
    return regexp.test(userAgent);
}

console.log(isMobile());
```

More notes on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent).

Anyway, you should be doing what you need to do in CSS instead of JavaScript unless you have a good justification.

Comment: These are changes in the original css properties (which in the case of margin-top is set to 0 in CSS, just as in the "else" and checkif() function ). So when you click elements from the navigation menu other ones move around and change color. if it's possible to do all of this on CSS would be happy to hear a solution!

Comment: I tried your isMobile() function and have the same issue, of the page grabbing the margin change from the switch instead of from isMobile()